# How to make movements respect camelCase or snake_case?

Tags: cursor-movement, letter-case

It is common to use either camelCase or snake_case to separate multiple words which form an identifier. It would be nice if the "word" movements (<kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>) would detect those inner-identifier boundaries.

How can this behavior be achieved? (Plugin/vimrc/...?)

Comment: I'd also like to know this for `snake_case`

Comment: You may be able to do something with the `iskeyword` setting, but I fear this will have many additional side-effects ... (see `:help word`).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I thought that it worked for `snake_case`. Seems that it doesn't, included it in the quesiton.

Comment: VimWiki's got you covered: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_through_camel_case_words I'll write up a proper answer at some point if someone else doesn't beat me to it.

Comment: I personally view a camalCased word as a whole word and don't like the idea of breaking half way into a word because of case or underscore. Usually I use the `f` and `t` keys to manage inner word movements.

Comment: @Sukima that's what I was doing until I asked this question, but it requires more "brain power" to think about which character to `t` to, instead of just going to the next capital letter.

Answer (score 16):

The plugin [CamelCaseMotion](https://github.com/bkad/CamelCaseMotion) does what you want. By default it maps to the keys `,w`, `,b`, `,e` which are equivalent to normal `w`, `b`, `e`. It works for both CamelCase and snake_case:

Example:

```
camelCaseWord
```

Using `d,w` will remove `camel`; using it again will remove `Case`.

Or with snake case:

```
snake_case_word
```

`d,w` will remove `snake_`, and on the second time it will remove `case_`.

"Inner" motions (such as `diw`) should also work as expected (as `di,w`).

If you prefer, you could also override the default `w`, `b`, and `e` with:

```
map <silent> w <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_w
map <silent> b <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_b
map <silent> e <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_e
sunmap w
sunmap b
sunmap e
omap <silent> iw <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_iw
xmap <silent> iw <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_iw
omap <silent> ib <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_ib
xmap <silent> ib <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_ib
omap <silent> ie <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_ie
xmap <silent> ie <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_ie
```

Comment: Note that this plugin's default mappings shadow the `,` command (repeat last `f`/`t`/`F`/`T` motion), meaning if you want to use that command, you'll have to wait for a delay (configured by `'timeoutlen'`). Fortunately, the plugin allows you to use alternative mappings of your choosing.

Comment: There seem to be some side-effects with this plugin, ie: `dw` on `, key);` when cursor is at `k` seems to remove the entire line (including newline), while I expected just `key` to be removed...

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/chaoren/vim-wordmotion) plugin to be better. Combining motion with deletion works properly, and it stops at brackets too.

Comment: Minor point, but in the first example it would surely remove `camel` and then `Case`, not `Word`?