# Define new text object for snake case

Tags: vimrc, custom-text-object

I recently discovered `iskeyword` as in `set iskeyword-=_` so that I can change just part of a snake case word, like changing `character_idx` to `char_idx` using `ciw`. This was working great, except sometimes I want to change the *entire* word, so I turned it off (it also was causing havoc with the syntax highlighting).

I am wondering if there is a way to define a new text object that is essentially `w` with `iskeyword-=_` set so that I could execute `ci\` (or something, I am not sure how to prevent collisions with vim commands already in existence) and change just part of a snake case word, while retaining `ciw` for whole snake case words.

I'm not even sure how to tag this.

Comment: Did you notice the question [How to make movements respect camelCase or snake_case?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/676/how-to-make-movements-respect-camelcase-or-snake-case) The answer also discusses text objects.