# Select first char up to first non camelCase or non upper case char or up to first snake case _ in vim

Tags: regular-expression

I used this map:

`map ,w v/\([^ a-z]*\|[^ A-Z]*\)<cr>h`

the idea is to select

in the words

```
mysuperTest
MYSUPER_TEST
mysuper_test
```

I want to be able to select 'test' and 'mysuper' depending if the caret is at the beginning, or the end of the string. The regex should work for mysuper but it doesnt. Not sure how to handle test

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/676/1841)

Comment: Exact duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60032848/9447571

Comment: @filbranden no it doesnt as I cannot use plugins