# How to change word within snake-case-variable?

Tags: replace

Consider following snake-case variable name, with the cursor somewhere within the word that we'd like to change.

```
roses_are_red_violets_are_blue
                 ^               # the cursor position where the change is due
```

Now I'd like to change `violets` to e.g. `tulips`, that is I'd like to find a good way of refering to a word that is enclosed with underscores. My best attempt so far uses searches to the start end end of the word:

```
T_ct_
```

but this feels terribly inefficient. (Especially considering that we have to use a combination that includes `[Shift]` three times, so that results in 6-7 keystrokes in total)

So I was wondering whether there is a more efficient way to do this.

In [How to make movements respect camelCase or snake_case?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/676/how-to-make-movements-respect-camelcase-or-snake-case) a plugin was suggested, but I'm interested to see if there is a way to do this in a plain VIM installation without having to rely on additional plugins or custom mappings.

Comment: To me this is a duplicate of this question [How to make movements respect camelCase or snake\_case?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/676/how-to-make-movements-respect-camelcase-or-snake-case) the same solution should apply here

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've found this before but I'd like to see if there is a better way in plain VIM that does not require any plugins. (I'll add that to the question.)

Comment: I think you already found the no config way. So what you need are the text objects created by the plugin so I'm not sure what you would consider a better way? Reimplementing the code of the plugin in your vimrc? I understand why one would want to avoid plugins and I think it's a sane goal but sometimes it just makes more sense to use a sane plugin rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I'm guessing you won't get much more efficient with native solution than `f`,`t` type motions...unless you code/map/macro a custom solution. BTW, IMHO it's a bit of a stretch to count a shift key as an extra keystroke. :)

Comment: For my personal computer I'm glad to use plugins and customize vim to my own taste, but sometimes I have to work on other computers where I'd like to avoid having to copy my own vimrc to/loading plugins etc, and I just encountered such a situation. But since I'd still consdier myself as a novice I thought maybe I overlooked some easier. I appreciate your help and I'll try to word my questions better in the future!

Comment: @BLayer It literally is a stretch for my pinkies:P

Comment: "Plugin" is basically a piece of VimScript. If you don't want a "plugin" you write VimScript yourself. By "plain Vim"  you probably mean predefined `:h text-objects`. However, there are only few of them. You can't do `ci_` unless you (or some plugin such as "targets.vim") has it defined. And without `:h text-objects` you're confined to motions, such as `T` and `t`.

Comment: Do you touch type? Anyways, that's not really any of my business... you're free to count it however you want...my point is more about what's generally considered to be a keystroke.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in `~/.vim/plugin/punctuation/text_objects.vim` to map most of these to do the right thing in operator-pending mode and visual mode. It won't always work perfectly, but it's been good enough for me for a while; add new punctuation by adding to the list.

```
if exists('g:punctuation_textobjects')
  finish
endif
let g:punctuation_textobjects = 1

let s:default_punct = [
      \ '_',
      \ '.',
      \ '/',
      \ '-',
      \ '*',
      \ '\|',
      \ '~',
      \ '!',
      \ '@',
      \ '#',
      \ '$',
      \ '^',
      \ '&',
      \ ]

function! s:create_i_map(char) abort
  if ! hasmapto(printf('i%s', a:char), 'vo')
    execute printf('xnoremap <unique> i%s :<C-u>normal! T%svt%s<CR>',
          \ a:char, a:char, a:char)
    execute printf('onoremap <unique> i%s :<C-u>normal vi%s<CR>',
          \ a:char, a:char)
  endif
endfunction

function! s:create_a_map(char) abort
  if ! hasmapto(printf('a%s', a:char), 'vo')
    execute printf('xnoremap <unique> a%s :<C-u>normal! F%svf%s<CR>',
          \ a:char, a:char, a:char)
    execute printf('onoremap <unique> a%s :<C-u>normal va%s<CR>',
          \ a:char, a:char)
  endif
endfunction

for char in get(g:, 'punctuation_chars', s:default_punct)
  call s:create_i_map(char)
  call s:create_a_map(char)
endfor
```

[Dotfiles link](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/plugin/punctuation_textobjects.vim)