# How to have w,e,b-based motions handle underscores without using iskeyword?

Tags: cursor-movement, cursor-motions, keyword

Using Neovim 0.6.1.

I use a lot of snake_case_variable_names and have a frequent need to navigate within their individual components instead of treating these names as a single word.

Right now, the only trick I've found is to put this line in my config: `set iskeyword-=_`

However this poses several problems:

1. When using the native completion engine, the individual components are registered in a list of available words. This tends to bloat completion lists with useless symbols (`some_integer`, `some`, `integer`).

   - For instance, if I declare `some_integer` in python, the jedi completion engine will recognise `some_integer` as a symbol available for completion. Which is good.
   - The native nvim completion engine, on the other hand, will recognise `some` and `word` as symbols available for completion. Which is bad.
2. The ability to navigate around full_names with w,e,b motions is either removed or severely impaired.

   - I can sometimes use `W,E,B` to select an entire_name, but it doesn't behave as `w,e,b` used to behave before using `set iskeyword-=_`. It usually overshoots and selects special characters such as parentheses, punctuation, brackets, etc.
3. `*` and `#` do not select the whole_name, but whatever word is delimited by underscores.

Does anyone know how I could get around either (hopefully both) of these problems?

Ideally, I'd like a setup that would function as follows:

- `w,e,b` to navigate within snake_case_names
- `W,E,B` behaving exactly as the default `w,e,b`

Answer (score 1):

Right before submitting this question I dove into a rabbit hole and emerged with a solution mentioned in this post: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/677/31358

The provided answer was to install this plugin: https://github.com/bkad/CamelCaseMotion

And with the following config, it seems that my wishes have been granted:

```
map <silent> b <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_b
map <silent> e <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_e
sunmap w
sunmap b
sunmap e
```

Comment: You forgot to remove `set iskeyword-=_` from your configuration file. This causes more problems than it solves. Keep the original `iskeyword` and use the CamelCaseMotion plugin.

Comment: Hey, good point. I just checked and I no longer have that bug and have removed the `iskeyword` line so maybe that completion curfufle was caused by neovim not being properly reset. Amending post.

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad both issues are fixed :)